# How to create a class which extends the SparseArray in Android?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extends

I want to create a class and it extends the **SparseArray**. The **mKeys** and **mValues** are private in SparseArray , so it cannot be accessed in my Class. But I need do some special things about the mKeys and mValues. How to handle it ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Comment: I don't know android, but generally this time (if you have to do something special) you might be better of applying the composition over inheritance principle, although I don't know your usecase

Comment: Could you provide more info about what you’re trying to achieve? Generally, there is no way to access a private member unless you use reflection, which I would’t recommend.

Comment: @curtisLoew Just want to accessed the private member. Can you explain the reflection way ? By the way, I want to say that the case just for study.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if mkey and mvalue are private and there is no geter and seter I don't think there is a way to access them in normal way without hacking code coz private modifier was designed to do not let developer access them